# how to undo any function

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there a way to undo last function/method which is just finished to work?

for example I have a function/method which is doing this:

```
isTrue = false
num+=5
```

and many more functions. Each function start to work when user presses certain button on a screen. User should have possibility to undo his last action.
Is there universal way to undo any function which just finished to work?

Of course, I can do this way:

```
 isTrue=true
 num-=5
```

but that to do if there is many functions? Is there easy way to undo any function (android)?

Comment: Please do not tag languages that are not related to your question.

Comment: If what you meant is only revert changes of variables/datasets, You can always implement memento pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built-in language feature to allow undoing everything that function has changed, but there are patterns that are established in other to help in these kind of situations.

One option you have is [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), where you keep copy of previous state, so that you can always comeback to it, but one drawback of this is increased memory usage for saving all excess state, or in case you are persisting state on disk then there is performance overhead for reading/writing.

Another option is using [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) where each command knows how to undo itself, this way you don't need to keep previous state, but you need to keep track of command history, what this means is that if you have a lot of state then command pattern would be better option because you don't need to save previous state but you will have a inverse function which knows to undo change that has been made by that command, while if you have only few strings then using memento pattern would be better option, especially if you need to allow undoing actions even after app is killed and started again.

Good example of using command pattern for undo with explanation can be found [here](https://matt.berther.io/2004/09/16/using-the-command-pattern-for-undo-functionality/).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any language or platform where you can do something like that.

Any code that your application executes modifies data in memory in some way (creates or destroys objects, changes values etc.). In order to undo changes made by that code operating system should save the full history of data modifications and that is practically impossible because of limited resources.